# Overrides not accepting the specified package in node v16?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, gatsby

In package.json, i specified to override "gatsby-transformer-remark" to use "sanitize-html":"2.7.3" but it always using older sanitize html version -1.27.5,

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby-transformer-remark":"5.24.0"
  }
  "overrides": {
    "gatsby-transformer-remark":{
      "sanitize-html":"2.7.3"
    }
  }
}
```

In package-lock.json , sanitize-html version specified as 1.27.5

```
"node_modules/gatsby-transformer-remark": {
      "version": "5.24.0",

      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
        "gatsby-core-utils": "^3.24.0",
        "sanitize-html": "^1.27.5",
        "underscore.string": "^3.3.6",
        "unified": "^9.2.2",
        "unist-util-remove-position": "^3.0.0",
        "unist-util-select": "^3.0.4",
        "unist-util-visit": "^2.0.3"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.15.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "gatsby": "^4.0.0-next"
      }
    },
```

But there is one another json element present in package-lock which overrides correctly.,

```
"gatsby-transformer-remark": {
      "version": "5.24.0",
      "requires": {
        "sanitize-html": "2.7.3",
        "underscore.string": "^3.3.6",
        "unified": "^9.2.2",
        "unist-util-remove-position": "^3.0.0",
        "unist-util-select": "^3.0.4",
        "unist-util-visit": "^2.0.3"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "mdast-util-to-string": {         
        },
      }
    }
```

After npm installation of those packages the transformer-remark using 1.26.5 only instead of 2.7.3, Am i missed anything here? Any help appreciated.